# Adding animation to Ruby on Rails site.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, animation

If I use JQuery to add animation to my Ruby on Rails web application, how is JQuery recognized by Rails? Is it just a matter of adding a Jquery gem? Or are some configuration instruction set in the code?

I'm still learning Ruby on Rails. And I would like to add custom animation to my home page but am not sure what tools/technology plays well with Ruby on Rails. JQuery, javascript, Ajax? Does anyone have any data regarding what percent of Rails application use which?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using Rails 3+ JQuery should be included by default.